# How to assign a class to an SVG element

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, svg, geometry

I'm trying to assign my variable pellet (which is a circle svg) to the class pelClass. For some reason it is not being assigned and is causing a lot of issues. Please help!

```
function positionPellet() 
{  
    constantCount = 1;

    while(pelletCount < constantCount*3)
    {
    var pellet = document.createElementNS( xmlns, 'circle' );
    pellet.setAttribute( 'cx', Math.random() * window.innerWidth );
    pellet.setAttribute( 'cy', Math.random() * window.innerHeight );
    pellet.setAttribute( 'r' , 10 );
    pellet.className = "pelClass"; //Pellet Class Adding
    pelletCount++;
    pelletList = new Array(pelletCount);
    pelletList.push(pellet);
    svg.appendChild(pellet);
    }
}
```

Comment: pelletList = new Array(pelletCount); ?  Do you really want to create a new array?  Maybe this statement should run before the loop

Comment: Did you try `pellet.class = "pelClass";`? Why did you describe your problem as "trying to assign a var to a class"? Shouldn't it be "trying to assign a class to an SVG element"?

Comment: code is working fine if you properly assign values to pelletCount , xmlns and svg.  Whats the issue ?

Comment: Your new problem is a totally different issue. You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In SVG the syntax is

```
pellet.className.baseVal = "pelClass"; //Pellet Class Adding
```

Or alternatively you can use setAttribute (which works the same as html)

```
pellet.setAttribute('class', "pelClass"); //Pellet Class Adding
```

Comment: It almost fixed my issue, see I needed this to be added to a class to check for collisions, when I ran this and it collided into the circle, it wasn't showing that the circle was associated with the appropriate class name.